# I cant get the value from selected option, what is wrong with these?

Tags: javascript

```
<select id="region_id" onChange="get_region_id()" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected>--Choose Region--</option>

  <?php foreach($region as $row){?>
  <option value="<?php  $row['region_c'];?>">
    <?php echo $row['region_m'];?>
  </option>
  <?php }?>

</select>
<?php ?> -----------------------

<script type="text/javascript">
  function get_region_id() {

    var select = document.getElementById('region_id');
    var options = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    alert(options);
  }
  get_region_id();
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to work: ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/y1e7qxba/)) - Please create a [mre]. Have you inspected your page source to ensure a valid value is being set, maybe `$row['region_c']` is giving you the wrong value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the function to an onChange event, so it triggers every time a new value is selected:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('region_id');

function get_region_id() {
  var options = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(options);
}

select.addEventListener('onChange',get_region_id)
```

```html
<select id="region_id" onChange="get_region_id()" class="form-control">
  <option disabled selected>--Choose Region--</option>
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
  <option value="four">four</option>
</select>
```